# Cannot get start time for event in Google calendar using Calendar APIs

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api, gdata

```
query = gdata.calendar.client.CalendarEventQuery()
query.max_results = 100
feed = calendar_client.GetCalendarEventFeed(CALENDAR_URL, q=query)

for i, an_event in enumerate(feed.entry):
   print an_event.when
```

Last line prints an empty list for all the events in the calendar. If I remove the CALENDAR_URL and use the default calendar for my account, then I can see the start/end times for each event. However, I cannot seem to do that for a shared calendar (although I can see all this information in the WebGUI and I also have all the permissions in place to modify the calendar with my username - even if I don't own it).

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?